# Updating a formula with data that is filtered

Tags: excel

I have a workbook that shows a list of data across roughly 8 columns (irrelevant). The columns can all be filtered. At the very end of the data set I have some formulas that are doing some calculations on the data (I have the formulas at the end in the same columns so I can filter the columns and my formulas will still show at the end of the data set).  Is it possible for me to be able to filter the columns and have the formula update to only include the VISIBLE data showing after I apply the filter?

Thanks in advance!

The formula I am using is a simple sum of a range that then divides by a constant in a separate cell from the data set.

Comment: What formula are you using? That's important detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use the subtotal formula when needing to filter.

Wrong formula: =SUM(B:B) / $E$1

Correct formula: =SUBTOTAL(9,B:B) / $E$1

[image: Unfiltered]

**after filtering...**

[image: Filtered]